# SQL transform table with multiple columns to two tables with FK between them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert my table with several fields to two other tables where one of the new tables has a row for each field in the first table in Microsoft SQL Server.

```
Table1(Table1Id, Field1, Field2, Field3)
```

for each row in Table1 create

```
Table2a(Table2aId)
Table2b(Table2bId, Table2aId, Field1)
Table2b(Table2bId, Table2aId, Field2)
Table2b(Table2bId, Table2aId, Field3)
```

**Details**
I currently have the table

Table1

```
[dbo].[CommunityAssetTemplates]  
      ,[CommunityId]  
      ,[CommunityAssetTemplateId]  
      ,[BaseHouseSpecsAssetId]  
      ,[CommunityLogoAssetId]  
      ,[CommunityMarketingMapAssetId]  
      ,[CommunityPhotoAssetId]  
      ,[CommunityVideoDraftAssetId]  
      ,[CommunityVideoAssetId]
```

This was mostly a quick way to fulfill a business need before we fully implemented the new feature where users can define multiple templates with different assets in them, so I made two new tables one is just to relate the second table to a Community

Table2a

```
[dbo].[CommunityAssetDataTemplates]  
,[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId]    
,[CommunityAssetTemplateTypeId]  
,[CommunityId]
```

Table2b

```
[dbo].[CommunityAssetTemplateFiles]  
,[CommunityAssetTemplateFileId]  
,[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId]  
,[CommunityAssetId]
```

These two tables map together like so, each Table1 row creates 1 Table2a row and 6 Table2b rows

Table2a

```
[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId] Auto Increments  
[CommunityAssetTemplateTypeId] = 1  
[CommunityId]  = Table1.CommunityId
```

Table2b - 1

```
[CommunityAssetTemplateFileId]  Auto increments  
    ,[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId] = Table2a.[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId]  
    ,[CommunityAssetId] = Table1.[BaseHouseSpecsAssetId] (THIS CHANGES)
```

Table2b - 2

```
[CommunityAssetTemplateFileId]  Auto increments  
    ,[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId] = Table2a.[CommunityAssetDataTemplateId]  
    ,[CommunityAssetId] = Table1.[CommunityLogoAssetId] (THIS CHANGES)
```

continues for the remaining 4 'AssetId's fields of Table1

Comment: would you please be so kind and serve us some code snippets - examples?

Comment: There are a number of ways this can be accomplished. First question, is the value for Table1Id going to be the same in Table2a? Or is it a whole new value (maybe using identity). What would really help here is if you would provide the ddl for the existing table and the two new tables.

Comment: Table2a will be a new table with no reference to Table1 and it's Ids do not matter. Table 1 will be deprecated and deleted later. I also added more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this using `CROSS APPLY` to separate `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Field3` columns into rows:

```
insert into Table2A (Table2Id)
select Table1Id from Table1

insert into Table2B(Table2Id, Field4)
select Table1Id, Field
from Table1
cross apply (values(Field1), (Field2), (Field3)) as ColumnsAsRows(Field)
```

Here is a sample:

```
declare @t1 table (Table1Id int identity(1,1), Field1 int, Field2 int, Field3 int)
declare @t2 table (Table2Id int primary key clustered)
declare @t3 table (Table3Id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, Table2Id int, Field4 int)

insert into @t1 (Field1, Field2, Field3)
values (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)

select * from @t1

insert into @t2 (Table2Id)
select Table1Id from @t1

insert into @t3 (Table2Id, Field4)
select Table1Id, Field
from @t1
cross apply (values(Field1), (Field2), (Field3)) as ColumnsAsRows(Field)

select * from @t2
select * from @t3
```

Comment: Table2Id cannot be assigned, so I cannot use Table1Id in place o0f Table2Id for  
insert into @t3 (Table2Id, Field4)
select Table1Id, Field  
Now thats an easy fix, but I have an error. I have edited my initial post with a current sctipt at the bottom.